# Youtube api running fine with html, incorrectly with aspx

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api

I'm relatively new with aspx and just tried to start moving my html page with youtube api with javascript into visual studio and aspx in order to move data into a database. In html the page seems to work fine and the next page button will successfully pass the pageToken. However, when I moved my html code to aspx, I noticed the page seems to refresh and drops my next page token, reloading the same front page. It also gives me a warning code that only occurs in aspx and not the html:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
Setting 'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is deprecated.
```

I am not adding any scripts using my jquerys, which I believe is the main cause of this warning. My nextPage function however does recall the api for additional requests.

In terms of moving the html to aspx all I do is copy all my html code and put it into the header and body respectively. Am I missing a step in migrating? Do I have to change my code when using aspx instead of html?

Here is my current ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #courses {
            width: 566px;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 556px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="video-container">
    <table><tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">
    <h1> Rutgers Accounting Digital Library Directory </h1>
    </td>
    <td align="right"><div id="summary"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td class="auto-style1"><form action="search_results.asp" method="Post"><input type="text" name="search1" placeholder="Search Here" size="20"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></form></td><td><form method="link" action="my_uploads.html" ><input type="Submit" name="Clear" value="Clear Filters"></form></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">
        <form>
        <select id="courses" onchange="show()">
        <option selected disabled>Select a Course</option>
        </select> 
        </form>
    </td></tr>
    <div class="button-container">      
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1"><button id="prev-button" class="paging-button" onclick="previousPage();">Previous Page</button></td>
            <td align="right"><button id="next-button" class="paging-button" onclick="nextPage();">Next Page</button></td>          
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <table id="results"></table>
        </tr>
    </table>        
    </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript page:

```
// Define some variables used to remember state.
var playlistId, nextPageToken, prevPageToken, status, cid;
var totalr = 0;
var rpp = 0;
var sum;
var dur = '';


function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', handleAPILoaded);
}

// After the API loads, call a function to get the uploads playlist ID.
function handleAPILoaded() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('APIKEY');
    requestUserUploadsPlaylistId();
}

// Call the Data API to retrieve the playlist ID that uniquely identifies the
// list of videos uploaded to the currently authenticated user's channel.
function requestUserUploadsPlaylistId() {
    // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
        part: 'contentDetails',
        forUsername: 'rutgersweb'
    });

    request.execute(function (response) {
        cid = response.result.items[0].id;
        dropdown(cid);
        playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
        requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
    });
}

// Retrieve the list of videos in the specified playlist.
function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, pageToken) {
    console.log(pageToken);
    $('#results').html('');
    console.log(pageToken);
    var requestOptions = {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 50
    };

    if (pageToken) {
        requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
    }
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);

    request.execute(function (response) {

        totalv = response.pageInfo.totalResults;
        rrp = response.pageInfo.resultsPerPage;
        sum = '<td>Results Per Page: ' + rrp + '</td><td>Total Pages: ' + Math.ceil(totalv / rrp) + '<td>Total Videos: ' + totalv + '</td>';
        $(sum).replaceAll('#summary');

        // Only show pagination buttons if there is a pagination token for the
        // next or previous page of results.
        nextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
        var nextVis = nextPageToken ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        $('#next-button').css('visibility', nextVis);
        $('#next-button2').css('visibility', nextVis);
        prevPageToken = response.result.prevPageToken
        var prevVis = prevPageToken ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        $('#prev-button').css('visibility', prevVis);
        $('#next-button2').css('visibility', nextVis);

        var playlistItems = response.result.items;
        if (playlistItems) {
            $.each(playlistItems, function (index, item) {
                displayResult(item.snippet);
            });
        } else {
            $('#results').html('Sorry you have no uploaded videos');
        }

    });
}

function getVideoDetails(mmp, ddp, yyyyp, dur, vidId, videoTitle, used) {
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        part: 'contentDetails',
        id: vidId
    });
    request.execute(function (response) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result.items[0].contentDetails.duration);
        str = str.replace(/"/g, "");
        str = str.replace(/PT/g, "");
        str = str.replace(/H/g, ":");
        str = str.replace(/M/g, ":");
        str = str.replace(/S/g, "");
        str = str.split(':');
        var ftime;
        if (str[1] < 10) {
            ftime = str[1];
            str[1] = '0' + ftime;
        }
        if (str[2] < 10) {
            ftime = str[2];
            str[2] = '0' + ftime;
        }
        displayOutput(mmp, ddp, yyyyp, str, vidId, videoTitle, used);
    });

}

// Create a listing for a video.
function displayResult(videoSnippet) {
    var videoTitle = videoSnippet.title;
    var videoId = videoSnippet.resourceId.videoId;
    var videoDescription = videoSnippet.description;
    var videoPub = videoSnippet.publishedAt;
    //dur = 

    //PublishedAt Formatting to compare
    ar3 = videoPub.split("T");
    uselessd = ar3[0];
    re = new RegExp("-", "g");
    uselessd2 = uselessd.replace(re, "/");
    usedd = uselessd2.split("/");
    ddp = usedd[2];
    mmp = usedd[1];
    yyyyp = usedd[0];

    //Description trimming to leave time stamps only
    ar = undefined;
    useless = undefined;
    useless2 = undefined;
    used = undefined;
    ar2 = undefined;
    ar = videoDescription.split("Time Stamps:");
    useless = ar[0];
    useless2 = ar[1];

    if (useless2 != undefined) {
        ar2 = useless2.split("Summary");
        ar = ar2[0];
        re = new RegExp("\n", "g");
        useless = ar.replace(re, "<br>");
        used = useless;
    }
    else
        used = " ";
    //  outputArray=[mmp, ddp, yyyyp, dur, videoId, videoTitle,used]
    //      displayOutput(outputArray);

    getVideoDetails(mmp, ddp, yyyyp, dur, videoId, videoTitle, used)
}

function displayOutput(mmp, ddp, yyyyp, dur, videoId, videoTitle, used) {

    //output = '<tr><td colspan="3" align="right">Published On: '+oarray[0]+'/'+oarray[1]+'/'+oarray[2]+'<br>'+dur+'</td></tr><tr><td><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+oarray[4]+'/1.jpg"></img></td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+oarray[4]+'">'+oarray[5]+'</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="right">'+oarray[6]+'<hr>';
    if (dur[2])
        output = '<tr><td colspan="3" align="right">Published On: ' + mmp + '/' + ddp + '/' + yyyyp + '<br>Length: ' + dur[0] + ':' + dur[1] + ':' + dur[2] + '</td></tr><tr><td><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoId + '/1.jpg"></img></td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '">' + videoTitle + '</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="right">' + used + '<hr>';

    else
        output = '<tr><td colspan="3" align="right">Published On: ' + mmp + '/' + ddp + '/' + yyyyp + '<br>Length: ' + dur[0] + ':' + dur[1] + '</td></tr><tr><td><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + videoId + '/1.jpg"></img></td><td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoId + '">' + videoTitle + '</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="right">' + used + '<hr>';

    //Append to results listStyleType
    $('#results').append(output);
}

// Retrieve the next page of videos in the playlist.
function nextPage() {
    console.log(nextPageToken);
    requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, nextPageToken);
}

// Retrieve the previous page of videos in the playlist.
function previousPage() {
    requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId, prevPageToken);
}


function dropdown(cid) {
    var requestOptions = {
        channelId: cid,
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 50
    };

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list(requestOptions);

    request.execute(function (response) {

        var plists = response.result.items;
        if (plists) {
            $.each(plists, function (index, item) {
                var drp = document.getElementById("courses");
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = item.snippet.title;
                optn.value = item.id;
                drp.add(optn);
            });
        } else;

    });
}

function show() {
    var e = document.getElementById('courses');
    var txt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    requestVideoPlaylist(txt);
}
```

I know the code is a little messy, still trying to get better coding habits, and I should probably fix some useless variables.

Comment: It is too difficult to tell what your problem is without seeing your code/markup. Can you post your `ASPX` at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `type="button"` on your button controls to prevent them from submitting the page each time they are pressed:

For example, in your ASPX page use:

```
<td class="auto-style1"><button type="button" id="prev-button" class="paging-button" onclick="previousPage();">Previous Page</button></td>
<td align="right"><button type="button" id="next-button" class="paging-button" onclick="nextPage();">Next Page</button></td>
```

Comment: wow. i can't believe i missed that. i was unaware that could even cause an issue like that. thanks so much!